# How do I add a percentage symbol at the emd of my output with no whitespace?

Tags: python, output, whitespace, symbols, percentage

My output on an assignment is correct except for the whitespace at the end of my output before the percent symbol.

My output :

> Your final grade is 86.75 %

Expected output (zybooks):

> Your final grade is 86.75%

What I have in my program:

```
print(f'Your final grade is',final_grade,'%')
```

Comment: `,` concatenation adds spaces between items, use f strings or +/& concatenation to avoid this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of f-strings more effectively when you do:
`print(f'Your final grade is {final_grade}%')`

You can read more about it here: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/